# cookie displayed in node console with Postman, not with browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

I execute exaclty the same query to my node API with Postman, and with browser. Node console show the good value of cookie with postman, undefined with browser. I am using axions for queries.

Here is my code in frontend (React) :

```
axios.post('auth', {
        withCredential: true,
        "name": this.state.login,
        "password": this.state.password
      })
      .then(function(response){
        if(response.data.xsrfToken != null){
          console.log(response.data.xsrfToken)
        }
        else{
          self.setState({
            errMess:response.data.message
          })
        }
      })
```

Here is my code in my API nodeJS :

```
         router.post('/auth', function(req, res, next){

                var token = jwt.sign(payload, secretWord, {
                       expiresIn : '24h'
                });

               var cookies = new Cookies(req, res, { keys: keys})

               cookies.set('access_token', token, { signed: true })

               console.log(cookies.get('access_token', { signed: true }))

               res.json({
                  success: true,
                  message: 'Token provided',
                  xsrfToken: payload.xsrfToken,
               });

            })

    app.use(cors({ origin:true, credentials:true }));

        // prevent CORS problems
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            next();
        })

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port 3001');
});
```

With Postman, the token is displayed in console and I can see the cookie set.

With a browser, I got undefined and I don't have any cookie.

Edit: Know that react App is running on port 3000 and node API is running on port 3001. So origin is not the same.

Edit: I tried to write console.log(req) into node.js server in the route /auth, I got :

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 374,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3001',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3001',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 6444,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 62328 },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 67,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 69,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 67 },
  connection:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 374,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3001',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3001',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 6444,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 62328 },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 67,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 69,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 67 },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: true,
  headers:
   { host: 'localhost:3001',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '38',
     accept: 'application/json',
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     referer: 'http://localhost:3000/connexion',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'Host',
     'localhost:3001',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive',
     'Content-Length',
     '38',
     'Accept',
     'application/json',
     'Origin',
     'http://localhost:3000',
     'User-Agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     'Referer',
     'http://localhost:3000/connexion',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip, deflate, br',
     'Accept-Language',
     'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/auth',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Array],
        timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
        data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Array],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 374,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3001',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3001',
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 8 },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 6444,
     _destroyed: false,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
        _sent100: false,
        _expect_continue: false,
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 62328 },
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 67,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 69,
     [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 67 },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/auth',
  _parsedUrl:
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/auth',
     path: '/auth',
     href: '/auth',
     _raw: '/auth' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res:
   ServerResponse {
     domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _headerSent: false,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _bytesDispatched: 374,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 6444,
        _destroyed: false,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _peername: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 67,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 69,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 67 },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _bytesDispatched: 374,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 6444,
        _destroyed: false,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _peername: [Object],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 67,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 69,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 67 },
     _header: null,
     _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
     _sent100: false,
     _expect_continue: false,
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {},
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      { 'access-control-allow-origin': [Array],
        vary: [Array],
        'access-control-allow-credentials': [Array],
        'access-control-allow-headers': [Array],
        'access-control-allow-methods': [Array],
        'x-dns-prefetch-control': [Array],
        'x-frame-options': [Array],
        'strict-transport-security': [Array],
        'x-download-options': [Array],
        'x-content-type-options': [Array],
        'x-xss-protection': [Array],
        'set-cookie': [Array] } },
  body: { name: 'CHARLAT', password: '184628' },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  read: [Function],
  route: Route { path: '/auth', stack: [ [Object] ], methods: { post: true } } }
```

Edit: It is not a CORS issue. I tried to open chrome with unsafe mode to disable CORS. Same result, I got undefined for my cookie.

Comment: Probably the payload being initiated by axios is empty. console.log the request issued by the browser and post the details

Comment: I have no idea about how to do that. For information, I tried : axios.defaults.withCredential = true; and the library axios-cookiejar-support.

Comment: add console.log(req) at top of your code in node.js. Go to the browser and send the request

Comment: This is done in edit. I thought about something. Can it happen because the API is in localhost and the react app too? Even with different ports?

Comment: I've written an answer to your problem. It is a CORS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the trick.

It was not a CORS problem. Because I tried with Chrome to start it with --disable-web-security, no change.

I also tried to change between axios and fetch, no change too.

The only way that it worked is with cookie-parser, and not with cookies library. By writing a simple :

```
res.cookie('user_token', token, { signed: true, httpOnly: true })
```

Then, to get your token, you need to write :

```
res.send(req.signedCookies)
```

After of course writing :

```
app.use(cookieParser(config.cookiesKey));
```

In server.js

This was for server side.

For client side, just write a fetch, seems to work really better than axios for cookies like this :

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          'name': self.state.login,
          'password': self.state.password
        }),
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body =>
        {
          if(body.success){
            console.log('On fait entrer le mec dans l\'appli')
          }
        }
       )
```

Be careful, the most important option is :

```
credentials: 'include'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [CORS issue](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). The scheme, url and port should match to let the browser set the cookies correctly.

To fix this, you have multiple options -

### 1. Mount both the react app and express on the same port.

Deliver the react app from the same express codebase running on the same port.
Say, `app.get("/app", reactApp)` to deliver the react app and `app.get("/api/*", apiCalls)` to deliver the API calls.

### 2. Use a reverse proxy like NGINX

You can use a reverse proxy like NGINX to run the website on port 80/443 and let it route to different ports to serve the react app and deliver the api calls. This is a good idea in production since front-end delivery can have different scaling requirements than an API server. Ideally, nginx itself should [deliver](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) your react app. Things get a little complicated when you have client side routing but this is still the preferred method.

### 3. Use CORS

This is possible, but not recommended if you do not know what you are doing. CORS should be enabled only when you explicitly need it. To enable cors, doing `app.use(cors())` should be sufficient for your use case.

```
    app.use(cors({ origin:true, credentials:true }));

    // prevent CORS problems
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    })
```

^ The second part (code under //prevent CORS problems) is just [duplicating](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) the effort of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. So I used the third method. With CORS. As you can see in my code. And I'm still having undefined in console for my cookie. Why? How will I check the token owned by the user? For you, what is the best method? The first one? The 2 projects (react and node) are separated in 2 folders. I use npm start for react and node server.js for node. How to meet the 2?